# Softphone with protocol to hang up the call

Tags: protocol

I am using self developed CTI system and trying to integrate with softphone.

Currently I have integrated with AGEphone (https://www.ageet.com/home-en) however, the quality of the sound is pretty bad. The only reason why I am using AGEphone is it has protocol to hang up the call.

So I was wondering if there are any other softphone which has protocols to hang up from browser feature.

Doesn't matter if the software is free or paid. Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that [crossposting is not welcome at SE sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/192154), even if they would fit on multiple of them. Ask the question on the site you think is most applicable. If it does not get any answer, ask a moderator to migrate the question, or alternatively, delete it and re-ask it. You've already posted [the identical question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787135/protocol-to-hang-up-from-browser-on-any-softphone), and didn't even check what you copy-pasted ("down vote favorite").

Answer (score 2):

Using Windows' protocol handler mechanism, tSIP - http://tomeko.net/software/SIPclient/browser_integration.php (free):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function hangup() {
    window.location = "tsip:HANGUP";
}
function call() {
    window.location = "tsip:" + document.getElementById("numberfield").value;   
}
```

or with direct link:

```
<a href="tsip:HANGUP">Hangup</a>
```

Probably also NCH Express: http://www.nch.com.au/talk/sdk.html